# combineLatest() does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, rxjs, electron

I have two sources: saveDialog$ and file$. The first is intended for picking asyncronously directory path for saving files which are emited by second source. I want to combine emited values so that i recieve the combination of once picked path with all files. I have tried to use combineLatest() but instead of 7 responses I had 1 with only latest file like this: `["path\to\dir", Object]`. ForkJoin emits the same.

Here is my code:

```
    const saveDialog$ = Observable.bindCallback(
        remote.dialog.showOpenDialog
    )(saveOptions).map(
        dirName => dirName ? dirName[0] : ''
    ).shareReplay(1);

    saveDialog$.combineLatest(
        file$
    ).subscribe(
        data => console.warn(data)
    )
```

How can I get 7 combined responses if 7 files are emited (for example)?

Comment: Is `file$` emitting each file as an individual value or does it emit arrays of file names?

Comment: Each file emits separately when source file$ is used independently

Comment: Where does `file$` come from? My guess is that `file$` dumps all 7 items immediately and the wait for the `saveDialog$` that happens after that. It makes just one emission because `combineLatest()` waits until it has at least one value from each source Observable.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://rxviz.com/v/xOvjkpO2) demonstrating what @martin said (and a link that shows you how to provide a small setup giving a reproducible environment for your question – you should be the one providing this!)

Comment: How can I pause emiting files until dir path is received? I need combination of two sources later for writing files to this diresctory in fs. Now it really writes only latest downloaded file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combineAll`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combineall.html) like this:

```
// Assume we emit 7 file names, starting immediately, but with some
// delay in between.
const file$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 300)
  .map(val => `file-${val}.png`)
  .take(7);

// Assume your path is emitted only after a bit of time has passed.
const saveDialog$ = Rx.Observable.of('path/')
  .delay(1000);

const result$ = saveDialog$
  // Map the path emission to the files observable.
  // This produces a higher-order observable.
  // To not lose the emitted path value, we map the emitted file
  // names together; instead of preparing the string here you
  // could also use
  //   file$.map(file => [path, file])
  .map(path => file$.map(file => `${path}${file}`))
  .combineAll();
```

You can find a working example [here](https://rxviz.com/v/Y86aleJ3).

---

As a side note, this only works with cold observables (you haven't specified whether your observables are hot or not). If `file$` is a hot observable, you'll need to multicast it through a `ReplaySubject`. [Here's](https://rxviz.com/v/9J9EM0Jl) a link that demonstrates this.

Comment: The idea with nesting observables helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concatMap` to wait until the `saveDialog$` emits the directory and then use `map()` to turn the emissions to the same format as you were using `combineLatest`.

```
saveDialog$
  .concatMap(dir => file$.map(f => [dir, f]))
  .subscribe(data => console.warn(data))
```